# Suppress default double-click event in SWT.CHECK Table

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, mouseevent

I am using a SWT Table styled with `SWT.CHECK` and `SWT.FULL_SELECTION`. I added a MouseListener to fill an output group, when a user double-clicks a table row. However, a double-click will also toggle the row's checkbox. Though I suppose this is intended behaviour of the target platform (Windows), I want to prevent the checkbox from toggling.

Is it possible to **not** make the checkbox toggle on double-click?

Comment: So which platform is this? On a Mac double click does not toggle the check box.

Comment: Neither on Windows...

Comment: I observed this behaviour on Windows 7.

Comment: @user1438038 Works just fine for me on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that the Table implementation I was using added a SelectionListener that toggled the checkbox.

When I removed it, everything worked as expected:

```
  Listener[] listeners = table.getListeners(SWT.Selection);

  if (listeners.length > 0) {
     TypedListener typedListener = (TypedListener)listeners[0];

     SelectionListener selectionListener = (SelectionListener)typedListener.getEventListener();

     table.removeSelectionListener(selectionListener);
  }
```

Ain't a clean solution, but since I know that the object only has one SelectionListener at that time, it seems legitimate to remove it this way.